# 'Referrer-Policy' 'Origin' not working in IE11

Tags: nginx, https, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, referrer-policy

I use nginx for https connection in my website and I need a connection to a Http server. For this purpose I use 'Referrer-Policy' 'Origin'. but this does not work in IE11.
 when I use  in html pages, everything is ok but when I use this command in nginx.conf nothing happens. why?

Here is my configs:
    location / {

```
      proxy_pass http://backends;
      proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      client_max_body_size 10m;
      client_body_buffer_size 2M;
      proxy_send_timeout 900;
      proxy_read_timeout 900;
      proxy_buffer_size 2M;
      proxy_buffers 4 2M;
      proxy_busy_buffers_size 2M;
      proxy_temp_file_write_size 2M;
      proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
      add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'Origin';


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer has been unsupported, aside from security fixes, for many years.

It is an obsolete browser that is only kept around by Microsoft because of the number of internal systems used by their customers which were designed in the 90s with only IE in mind.

The `Referrer-Policy` HTTP header is too new to be supported by IE.